# Laravel Eloquent: with() vs join() JSON Output

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I have these 2 queries on my Laravel project:

```
$questions = \App\Answer::rightJoin('questions','answers.id_question','=','questions.id_question')
        ->leftJoin('users','answers.id_user','=','users.id')->where([
            ['questions.id_question', '=', $id_question],
            ['questions.flg_active', '=', true],
        ])->orderBy('questions.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

and

```
 $questions = \App\Answer::with('question.user')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

Essencially the first on returns questions not yet answered and the second only returns questions already answered. 
I`m trying to use the same blade view for both, but they have different JSON output structure.

The first one returns an one level JSON, while the second returns 3 levels of data.

```
"data": [{
        "id_answer": 42,
        "created_at": "2018-11-28 17:52:18",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-24 15:09:14",
        "id_user": 2,
        "id_question": 42,
        "str_answer": "onono onooono nonono onn ",
        "str_question": "ononon ononon onononn ?",
        "url_link": null,
        "flg_active": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Paul",
        "surname": null,
        "email": "p@yahoo.com",
        "certification": "CFA ...",
        "about": "CS, ....."
    }
```

and:

```
"data": [{
        "id_answer": 64,
        "created_at": "2019-05-16 15:46:54",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-16 15:46:54",
        "id_user": 2,
        "id_question": 98,
        "str_answer": "onono non ooonononn",
        "question": {
            "id_question": 98,
            "created_at": "2019-05-16 15:06:31",
            "updated_at": "2019-05-16 15:24:43",
            "id_user": 2,
            "str_question": "onono onnon ononon?",
            "url_link": null,
            "flg_active": 1,
            "user": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Paul",
                "surname": null,
                "email": "p@outlook.com",
                "created_at": "2018-12-06 05:50:09",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-24 11:23:32",
                "certification": null,
                "about": null
            }
        }
    }
```

**How can I make the first one return in the same 3 levels as the second query does ?**

**Why this occurs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is leveraging query builder more and will execute one query which will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM answer
RIGHT JOIN questions ON answers.id_question = questions.id_question
LEFT JOIN users ON answers.id_user = users.id
WHERE questions.id_question = $id_question
AND questions.flg_active = true
ORDER BY questions.created_at desc
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 15
```

This query returns data from all the tables exactly how sql calculates it. Laravel / Eloquent has no idea how to reliably put this into an eloquent format.

The 2nd one will execute 3 queries which will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM answer
ORDER BY created_at desc
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 15

SELECT * FROM question
WHERE answer_Id IN ($answer_ids) // Will be like (1, 5, 6, 7). All the ids retrieve from the first query

SELECT * FROM user
WHERE queston_id IN ($user_ids)
```

Eloquent does 3 queries therefore it can create the structure you outlined reliably.

Ultimately it's a trade off, the first option is faster but the response is harder to work with in php which creates less readable code.

I recommend you look at the queries that are executed by each by using the built in query log.

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$builtQuery->get()
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because in your second query you utilize [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for your Eloquent relationships. Eloquent model's default `toArray()` method merges both it's attributes and loaded relationships into one representation.

On the other hand, your first query joins tables, but doesn't load any relationships. So the most straight-forward way you can go about this is to eager load those relationships in your first query just as you do in your second one:

```
    $questions = \App\Answer::with('questions.user')           
        ->rightJoin('questions','answers.id_question','=','questions.id_question')
        ->leftJoin('users','answers.id_user','=','users.id')->where([
            ['questions.id_question', '=', $id_question],
            ['questions.flg_active', '=', true],
        ])->orderBy('questions.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

Note that this will produce extra `SELECT ... WHERE id IN (...)` queries for both `Question` and `User` models to be eager loaded into their respective relationships.

Comment: Updated both queries with eager load, but with with([‘question’,’user’]). Now the first one retrieves user from question, while 2nd retrieves user from answer (what I want). Why?

Comment: @Paulo your join might be messing up eager loading since both answer and question tables have `id_user` column (and you join by it). Add `->select('answers.*')` to your first query (where `answers` is your table's name).